# No sound on internal laptop speakers (but wired headphones are OK)

Tags: sound, alsa, laptop, speakers

Ubuntu 23.04. No sound from laptop speakers, but wired headphones work fine. Bluetooth ones also work if it matters. System properly detects when headphones are connected and switches from speakers to headphones and vice versa.

From my investigation it seems like drivers don't enable speakers amplifier or something like that. Just some tiny bit is missing. I have tried some tweaks to alsa-base.conf from recommended over Internet - no luck.

Weird thing is it all worked some time ago! I don't remember exact moment when it had stopped, because I usually use headphones. May be related to proprietary nVidia drivers I've installed some time ago. But I have tried to boot Ubuntu 23.04 and 22.04 from live USB with just open drivers - still no sound.

I can't check if it works with Win at the moment.

So, any ideas how to fix that? Also where it would be proper to post this in ALSA project? I'm not sure to which part this belongs to. At least it's not kernel I think (I've tried different ones for different reason, but anyway).

[ALSA info](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=b6fec159dde600e2ff570f9185e0092756418155)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by applying latest BIOS firmware update.

Its changelog mentioned only fixing some noises (on Win I assume), but it also fixed this issue as well.

Laptop model is MSI Cyborg 15 A12VF. It's quite new, so no wonder some bugs were there...

UPD: Month later sound on speakers is broken again. It seems to be related to unplugging headphones amid shutdown process.